# put exec output in a variable

Tags: ruby, variables, command-line, exec

I am new to ruby and trying to do some command line stuff.

Now I need to **save the output** of

```
exec 'cat /etc/system-release'
```

in a **variable** to scan it for a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grab the output you're better off using `system` or backticks (or for  longer running tasks, `IO.popen`)

In this case, it would be a lot faster to do

```
File.read('/etc/system-release')
```

rather than creating extra processes just to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for formatting and the hints. I will use `File.read` now :)